# How do i use KineticJS polygon object with geoJSON coordinates rather than points?

Tags: html, gis, kineticjs, geojson

I am creating an interactive map on HTML5 canvas using KineticJS, problem is my map data is in geoJSON, so i have polygon coordinates rather than polygon points.

This is how i would do it with polygon points([according to this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/404239/HTML5-Interactive-Map-using-SVG-Path-and-Polygon))

```
    //Javascript object with map data
    var myMap = {
    'Russia': {
     points: [44,1,397,1,518,2,518,151,515,..............6,43,4,43,4]
    },
    'Azerbaijan': {
     points: [198, 242, 201, 245, 203,..............197, 242]
    },
    'UAE': {
     points: [224,406,225,410,...............225,407]
    }
   };

    //Function to return map data
    function getData() {
    return myMap;
    }
```

Then use the KineticJS polygon object to draw the map on HTML5 canvas.

```
     //store map data in a variable
     var areas = getData();

    //Loop through the map
    for (var key in areas) {
        (function () {
            var k = key;
            var area = areas[key];
            var points = area.points;

            var shape = new Kinetic.Polygon({
                points: points,
                fill: '#fff',
                stroke: '#555',
                strokeWidth: .5,
                alpha: 0.1
              });

            } ());
        }
```

Does anybody know how i can achieve the same with geoJSON coordinates? Here is a sample of the geoJSON. The coordinates are nested inside the geometry object.

```
        {
"type": "FeatureCollection", 
"features": [{ "type": "Feature", "id": 0, 
"properties": { "OBJECTID_1": 29, "OBJECTID": 29, "COUNTY_NAM": "BARINGO", "COUNTY_COD": 30, "Shape_Leng": 5.81571392065, "Shape_Area": 0.88451236881 }, 
"geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 36.028686523000033, 1.276123047000056 ], [ 36.036499023000033, 1.263916016000053 ], [ 36.039306641000053, 1.259887695000032 ],............[ 36.028686523000033, 1.276123047000056 ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, KineticJS latest two releases support an array of arrays to be given as points. But what you should do is create a loop which parses through the coordinates objects and grabs all the values sequentially, as that is all KineticJS needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var myArray = new Array();
  for( var level1 in coordinates ){ // for each array in coordinates
       for( var level2 in level1){    // for each array in that array
            for( var number in level2){   // for each number in that array
                myArray.push(number);
            }
       }
  }
  var points = myArray;
```

Maybe this is too many levels of nesting, but this is the main idea:

Go through all the sub arrays and grab the numbers in each and place them in a new array.

Answer (score 0):

Polygon object accepts data as an array OR Point Objects, which has x and y.

```
var polygonData = coordinates.map( function(cord) {
  return {x:cord[0],y:cord[1]};
})

//excample
array = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
array.map( function(cord) {
  return {x:cord[0],y:cord[1]};
})
// will return [{x:1,y:2},{x:3,y:4}, {x:5,y:6}]
```

Or, if you want to get an array only(no x,y)

```
var flattened = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]].reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
});
// flattened is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```